# Repeatedly Changing a color Based a randome number generated

Tags: jquery, html, css

So this page generates a random number between 0 and 180 every 4 seconds. The number is assigned to changingSpeed. Were attempting to change a background color, over and over, based on the random number each time it changes. It almost works.. but the conditional only triggers the **else**, not the **if** or the **else if**.

```
<code>
<script>
/*  I set the interval to 4 seconds   4000ms */
var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber();},4000);

function randomNumber()
{

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*180);
  //Do whatever you want with that number
  $('#changingSpeed').html(rand);


if (changingSpeed <= 60) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2 )');
} else if (changingSpeed <= 120) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2 )');
} else {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2 )');
}


}

</script>


<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.39.14"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit   ({"static":"http://static.jsbin.com","root":"http://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script>


/* Generate a random number  */
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore    (a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-   analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'auto');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Where you have declared the variable `changingSpeed` in it?

Comment: I thought it could possibly on be triggering once. But no matter what the first number generated is.. the third color is triggered.

Comment: Use `var changingSpeed = rand` instead of `$('#changingSpeed').html(rand);`

Comment: I didn't declare it, but the number is set equal to changingSpeed  This shows the number just fine <div id='changingSpeed'></div>

Comment: Then how can you check it in `if` statement? or you can directly check `rand` like `if (rand <= 60)....`

Comment: I thought it might be like other languages where you don't "have to" declare... I didn't  declare but this shows me the number as it changes. <div id='changingSpeed' class="spedo"></div>

Comment: I'm still extremely new to jQuery and JavaScript.. So there is an ignorance factor here :-)

Comment: checkout my answer :) it's working fine there https://jsfiddle.net/m38cuo78/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine 
here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m38cuo78/)

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script></head><body>

<div id=meter_box style="width:50px; height:50px;"></div>
<script>
/*  I set the interval to 4 seconds   4000ms */
var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber();},4000);

function randomNumber()
{

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*180);
  // define the changingSpeed var as rand;
  var changingSpeed = rand;


if (changingSpeed <= 60) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2 )');
} else if (changingSpeed <= 120) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2 )');
} else {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2 )');
}


}

</script></body></html>
```

Comment: When I run it with this in the body. <div id="meter_box"></div> it only changes color to red no matter what the initial number or other subsequent  numbers.

Comment: it changes randomly between the three colors every four seconds, you was missing to declare the `changingSpeed` variable

Comment: Took it home last night and the answer was staring Me in the face. Got it all working...  Thanks for every ones help... Much appreciated!  Still Learning...

Comment: you welcome, can you select the answer as accepted then so the thred is closed